# Items in drop down menu are not visible

Tags: css

Can somebody tell me, how can I fix the drop down menu? Some items are not visible, because menu is on the two lines and the second line hidden items in drop down menu. I think that good solution will be with css code, but I dont know how.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `z-index` issue, you haven't specified the `z-index` for the sub-menu. The fix is to add the following CSS to set the `z-index` to the sub-menu:

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li:hover > ul.sub-menu {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

**Preview**

[image: working]

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index` and `top` properties to `ul.sub-menu` which fades in on-hover,

Update - Just by changing `z-index` as suggested by Praveen Kumar works. So if you add top property to `ul.sub-menu` will somewhere break your structure.

> z-index : The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a
>   positioned element and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order
>   determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger
>   z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.08);
    top: 35px; /*Add this*/
    z-index: 9; /*Add this*/
}
```

Comment: Why `top: 35px;`?

Comment: Umm... Why `top: 35px;`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Okay z-index only works, as it was position absolute, so I added both top:0 and z-index which break structure, so later I added top 35px.

Comment: Actually, the thing is, you don't need `top` at all. That's why.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes I got that was updating my solution. Thanks.